# Bug while recording Axis camera stream with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, rtsp

I am using FFMPEG to record the video stream (h264 / AAC in MP4) provided by an AXIS camera ([P1346](http://www.axis.com/products/cam_p1346/)).

I need to make recordings at specific times. To achieve this, I use a PHP script which is executed every minute (with **cron**), checks in the database whether a recording should be started or not.

To record the stream, I use **proc_open** with the following command line:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://192.168.0.103:554/axis-media/media.amp?udp&buffer_size=65535' -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 3600 -y '/path/to/video/folder/file.mp4'
```

Problem is, it works in most cases, but the recording fails every now and then. Have anyone ever tried to record AXIS streams in command line, and faced bugs while doing it?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Mathieu

N.B.: I have encountered the same difficulties using VLC.

**EDIT:** Network errors can be a good explanation on why the recordings sometimes suddenly interrupt; however, I still don't understand why the whole video file is corrupted after that.

Comment: How does it fail? output? segfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this issue before when the connection between the server and the camera is interrupted or degraded.  We were pulling a feed from a camera over a wireless connection and the periodic latency was an issue.   Check the health of the network and the server pulling the stream.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. There is nothing to worry about regarding the server; however, I already had some concerns about the health of the network. What I don't understand about it is that when the recording fails, the resulting video file is completely unreadable, and the codecs are not even recognized by FFMPEG...

Comment: Check the version of FFMPEG you are running and try the latest build.  There was an issue with damaged headers that made the file unreadable.  You might have a combination of issues between the network and FFMPEG version.  The easist way to rule out FFMPEG is to run it at the command line and watch for any errors kicked out.  You should know pretty quickly if that is the issue.

Comment: Late answer... haven't read that post in a while.
I had checked my scripts a thousand times, and tested them directly using command line with no results.
Network trouble it was indeed.